# Laravel: Displaying the list with same URL when clicking the html button

Tags: php, laravel, routes, show-hide

I'm facing an issue, please see the below screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82x8j.jpg)

In the screenshot, you can see its image upload page. By default, the **Add Image** button and the table which showing the lists should be display. The concept that I want to implement is when I click the **Add Image** button, the table lists should be hidden and have to show the image upload section. This all should be happen in the same URL.

Below is the code:

**Route:**

```
Route::post('/imageupload', 'Admin\ImageController@imageUploadPost')->name('image.upload.post');
```

**Blade File:**

```
<div class="panel panel-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Image</button>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-container">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="slideshow">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-container hide-img-upload">
    <form action="{{ route('image.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            @csrf


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function imageUploadPost()

    {
  return back()

            ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.')

            ->with('image',$imageName);

    }
```

Since, I'm new to Laravel, I couldn't able to see the solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use modal.it will help you

Comment: That's more of a `javascript/css` question than a Laravel one

Comment: @kerbholz, Thanks. Can you please give me some example

Comment: You can use the Bootstrap4 class `.d-none` to hide content. And use `$("#yourId").toggleClass('d-none');` to toggle visibility of that element. Or try one of the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="panel panel-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal">Add Image</button>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-container">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="slideshow">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
 <div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog"
         aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Image </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                </div>
                <div class="container"></div>

                <div class="panel panel-container hide-img-upload">
                    <form action="{{ route('image.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        @csrf


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>


            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

or use javascript hidden show for this

Answer (score 0):

this is more about html and javascript staff.
You can use this as hint.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="alter()">Alter</button>
    <div id="first">First</div>
    <div id="sec">Second</div>

    <script>
document.getElementById('sec').style.visibility = 'hidden';
function alter(){
  if(document.getElementById('sec').style.visibility == 'hidden'){
    document.getElementById('sec').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('first').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }else{

    document.getElementById('sec').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('first').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly define id for file input;

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="file_input" class="form-control">
```

After define id for list scope;

```
<div class="panel panel-container" id="list_scope">
```

Finally add JavaScript codes;

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('file_input').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('list_scope').style.display = "none";
    };
</script>
```